# Ability to mount the same tmpfs more than once

Tags: mount, tmpfs

Why is the following possible?

```
root@pkara-pc01:~# mkdir -p /tmp/shared
root@pkara-pc01:~# mount -t tmpfs -o size=1G mymount /tmp/shared/
root@pkara-pc01:~# mount -t tmpfs -o size=1G mymount /tmp/shared/
root@pkara-pc01:~# mount | grep -i shared
mymount on /tmp/shared type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=1048576k)
mymount on /tmp/shared type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=1048576k)
```

**edit**: I am asking because normally, trying to mount an already mounted fs is supposed to fail (?)

```
$ mkdir -p mydir
/tmp
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=myfile bs=1M count=1000
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB, 1000 MiB) copied, 0.563994 s, 1.9 GB/s
/tmp
$ mkfs.ext4 myfile 
mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Discarding device blocks: done                            
Creating filesystem with 256000 4k blocks and 64000 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 95fe153e-a575-4c9a-beef-b7a20a6ae342
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (4096 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

/tmp
$ sudo mount -o loop myfile /tmp/mydir/
/tmp
$ sudo mount -o loop myfile /tmp/mydir/
mount: /tmp/mydir/: /tmp/myfile is already mounted.
```

Comment: Why should it not be possible? I mean, what would the rationale for disallowing it be?

Comment: pls check my update

Comment: But `tmpfs` is not mounting an already mounted filesystem.  It's not clear if the issue is mounting multiple things onto the same mountpoint (as it says in the title), or whether it's about mounting the same thing twice (which the added text in the question tries to do).

Comment: you are right about the ambiguity so I updated the question title;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `tmpfs` is a virtual file-system, in the sense that it does not have, nor need, a backing storage to write its metadata on to.

Instead, the `ext4fs` is a persistent file-system, it requires a backing storage (be it an image file or a true device) to write its metadata on to.

So your `mount` command for the `tmpfs` case is just *re-using* the same directory to mount *another* (though again tmpfs), completely pristine, file-system. This is allowed, even if that directory were already in use as mount-point for a persistent file-system like `ext4`: a second `mount` would just override the previous file-system, which would re-appear as it was when you’d unmount the second file-system.

Instead, your `mount` command for the `ext4` case is trying to mount that *same backing storage* (the `myfile` file) more than once and on to the same mount-point, and that’s why you get the error message. This can never happen for virtual file-systems like `tmpfs` because they don’t have a (external) backing storage at all. In fact the `mymount` piece of your command for `tmpfs` is only a place-holder to make `mount`’s syntax content. You can use any arbitrary string there for a `tmpfs`. On the contrary, the `myfile` piece in your command for the `ext4` case *has to be* something already existent and available on the system, which will be used as backing storage for the persistent file-system (even if you put that backing storage in a actually volatile file-system like `tmpfs`, the `mkfs.ext4` command and the `ext4fs` driver does not know/care about that).

However, note also that since the venerable v2.4 linux kernel it is possible to safely mount multiple times file-systems like `ext4` too, *as long as* they are mounted on to different mount-points (i.e. not on the same directory as in your example). Basically such multiple mountings behave like a `mount --bind`. Notably, though, this behavior cannot be obtained for `loop` block devices if they are created from the same backing file on different `/dev/loopX` numbers, which is the behavior that `mount -o loop` had until its version 2.28.x. Starting from v2.29 it detects if it’s going to reuse the same backing file and will silently turn that into a `mount --bind` equivalent.

For safety, do not use version 2.28.x or lower of `mount` with `-o loop` more than once on the same backing file (unless you un-mounted it in between).  Possible outcomes include a kernel crash, and hence loss of arbitrary data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92795/discussion-between-ll3-and-sourcejedi).